# unreal engine 4 making a cable wrap around objects

Tags: unreal-engine4, nvidia-flex

does anyone know how to make a cable component respond to being blocked by other physics components in unreal engine 4?  game has a swinging rope that should wrap around objects it hits, instead every setting I try it is still passing through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cable component isn't fully fleshed out, in that it doesn't do any kind of collision work. If you want cables that can wrap, look at NVidia FleX (they have a github with a working implementation in 4.15)

Comment: I'm not the programmer on this one, but I sent a link to FleX to the development team, to see if they can code it in.  thanks for the heads up, it looks like that's what we need, if we can make it work with UE4.